# ¿Para el lado del servidor, cuándo se debería usar PHP y cuándo JavaScript con Node.js? ¿Que diferencias hay?

Tags: php, javascript, nodejs

Desde mi completa ignorancia, he leido en varios sitos que la industria tecnológica actual apuesta más por aplicaciones web completas en JavaScript (Node para el back y frameworks actuales para el front) que por utilizar PHP para la parte del servidor.

Comment: ¿Porqué dices que php está en decadencia? por otro lado, php se interpreta en el lado del servidor mientras que los otros que nombras son basados en javascript, normalmente en el lado del cliente, digamos que juntando las dos tecnologías tienes lo que se entiene como una web, se complementan pero no son alternativas. Una alternativa a php sería .NET, node js en el lado del servidor, python o ruby, pero no React o Vue.

Comment: Esto es más una queja social que una consulta. Partiendo de que PHP no está en decadencia, es más, hace poco han sacado otra actualización, y se espera la siguiente para no dentro de mucho, es un lenguaje de servidor, no comparable, en ningún caso, a JS y derivados. Con JS no desarrollas una web, solo desarrollas parte, pero con PHP puedes hacer una web funcional y, hasta cierto punto, prescindir de JS, eso sí, trabajarás el doble para hacer lo mismo que con JS. Por otro lado, si conocieras PHP sabrías las cositas que se han agregado en la nueva versión, haciendolo, casi, una nueva tecnología.

Answer (score 3):

Sea un lenguaje en decadencia o no, PHP no se puede comparar con los **frameworks de JavaScript** que acabas de nombrar.

PHP es un lenguaje de programación. Node.js no es un lenguaje de programación es mas bien un interprete de JavaScript.

En primer lugar React y PHP no son comparables. React es una biblioteca de JavaScript para construir interfaces de usuario. PHP es un lenguaje de programación de uso general que se usa en los servidores web para desarrollar aplicaciones web.

En el caso de Vue.js es mas de lo mismo.

No comparto tu opinión respecto a dejar de enseñar PHP, si yo fuera ellos daría tanto PHP como los Frameworks nombrados, ya que juntando estos "Lenguajes" se pueden conseguir grandes resultados.

Espero que le sea útil la información.